# live() and on() method, and FF browser

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery, jquery-on

I have this code that use live method, and it works in Opera and Chrome:

```
 $(".dynamicaly_created_div").live("click",function(){
    $(event.target).parent().remove();
 });
```

But not in the FF. So i tried to replace "live" with "on" (i read somwhere that live is deprecated). But then, this does not work in any browser.

Is ther any solution for this?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you are using? A little important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried passing the event into the function?

```
$(".dynamicaly_created_div").live("click",function(e){
    $(e.target).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Yes, this works, tnx a lot :) And, yes, i tried something like this, but i did not used it correctly, so it did not worked.